# openpyxl iter_rows throwing type error with current version?

Tags: openpyxl

I feel like there has to be something incredibly simple I'm missing here.. there are a couple stackoverflow questions but they all end with "upgrade openpyxl" -- which doesn't apply here  ;-)

The entirety of the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.iter_rows(min_row=1)
```

I have current openpyxl... python 3.8...

```
rtp-ads-1024:~/ws/gitz/powerInventory > pip3 freeze | grep pyxl
openpyxl==3.1.2

rtp-ads-1024:~/ws/gitz/powerInventory > /usr/bin/env python3 --version
Python 3.8.12
```

when I run that code...

```
rtp-ads-1024:~/ws/gitz/powerInventory > ./foo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./foo.py", line 7, in <module>
    ws.iter_rows(min_row=1)
TypeError: iter_rows() got an unexpected keyword argument 'min_row'
```

it's still in the docs and this seems like an incredibly fundamental thing to remove/change...

https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.2/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html?highlight=iter_rows#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.iter_rows

Comment: I try the same and it's working. Have you tried running it `python foo.py`?

Comment: `rtp-ads-1024:~/ws/gitz/powerInventory > python --version
Python 3.8.12`
`rtp-ads-1024:~/ws/gitz/powerInventory > python ./foo.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./foo.py", line 7, in <module>
    ws.iter_rows(min_row=1)
TypeError: iter_rows() got an unexpected keyword argument 'min_row'`

Comment: Open a python terminal (run `python`) and type ` openpyxl.__version__` to make sure you use the correct version.

Comment: As @LoukasPap that parameter has not been removed from the latest release of Openpyxl 3.1.2 so it would appear you not running the version you think you are. Check the version in terminal as suggested or include the line `print(openpyxl.__version__)` in your code or if you're using an IDE you should be able to call `usages` for iter_rows()` and/or open the openpyxl file `worksheet.py` and view the code/usage.

Comment: The API hasn't changed for years so you must have broken something in your install.

Comment: Thanks.  How on earth is one supposed to know to look for something like this given the error message?  the -1 here seems quite harsh given that I provided both the python AND openpyxl versions, demonstrating that at least I know enough to think about versioning issues...